# App pool settings for Exchange Server 2013 IIS and Processor Affinity

Tags: exchange-2013, iis-8.5

Is it ok to enable processor affinity on the Exchange 2013 app pools? I am running on vmware and have multiple sockets / cores. I see that the defaults are false to Processor affinity.

Will this cause any issues or break anything?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? VMware is a company, not a hypervisor or virtualization platform, what VMware hypervisor or virtualization platform are you using?

Comment: Just trying to point out the environment IIS and exchange are running in are virtualized

Comment: Right, we got that. My point was in asking what virtualization platform/product/hypervisor are you using? VMware Workstation? VMware Player? vSphere? What? Why do you want to set the processor affinity for the Exchange IIS app pools?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about setting processor affinity in the operating system, not in the properties of the virtual machine, right?

Comment: Vsphere sorry :)

Comment: Processor Afinity in the IIS App Pool